# Is there a way to additional download and integrate activities and .xml?

Tags: java, android

I want to make an app where the the user can choose what parts of the app he wants to use. On the start the app, it should only contain the part of the code (to be very small) where the user can choose additional parts and install it. Then additional code should be downloaded from a sever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try Google's App Bundler. Google provides this on android apps. You can create many of those bundlers, and delivery only those your users need.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/